# CSS box-shadow, top inset and bottom standard

Tags: html, css

I have `p` element, and I want to put top box-shadow inset, and bottom standard. Can this be done via CSS or it is better to use images for this effect?

```css
.mali_oglas_text:before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%; height: 20px;
    top:0; left:0;    
    z-index: -1;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.mali_oglas_text {clear: both; margin: 0 5px; padding: 7px; background: white; position: relative;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow:         0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<p class="mali_oglas_text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. 
 </p>
```

Comment: Yes, but I am not skilled with it. I found solutions on net how to do top and bottom, inset or standard, but I cann't find solution for this combination.

Comment: create a fiddle and show us what you got http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you want to do something more than just a quick hack, I suggest you go through this entire section, both reading and testing: https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.shadow
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 4px -4px #0f0, 
-moz-box-shadow: inset    0px 3px 10px #0f0;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #2a2a2a;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 10px #2a2a2a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .mali_oglas_text:before{
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 164px;
            top:0;
            left:0;    
            z-index: 9999;
            box-shadow: 0px 10px rgba(221,221,221);
            position: absolute;
        }
        .mali_oglas_text {
            clear: both;
            margin: 30px;
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 26px;
            background: white;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }
        h1 {
            clear: both;
            margin: 30px;
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 26px;
            background: white;
            box-shadow: inset 0 10px 5px #dbdbdb, 0 6px 0px #dbdbdb;
        }
```

```html
<p class="mali_oglas_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis.</p>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi mauris, egestas ut luctus sit amet, gravida et libero. Morbi mollis nisi vitae urna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus egestas ornare facilisis.</h1>
```